# Javascript regExp - find brackets

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't figure out how to search for a string containing something like "[1]", for some reason this doesn't work:

```
var regExp = '/\[[1-9]\]/';
var search = string.search(regExp); // returns -1
```

I've searched all over for a solution but can't find anything...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try it without the `'`

```
var regExp = /\[[1-9]\]/;
var search = string.search(regExp);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the way you're actually attempting to match it. Try this:

```
string="something[1]";
if(string.match(/\[[1-9]\]/gi)) alert("Your string has brackets with a number inside!"); //Alerts correctly
```